# preg_match - url validation, whats wrong?

Tags: url, preg-match

I want to check the syntax of an value, but my code wont work.

```
preg_match("/^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/", $_POST['website']
```

it should be check there is

1) http or https
2) a part with ://
3) a part with a-z/0-9
4) a point
5) a part with a-z min/max characters

Here is the part of the php-file

> in $_POST['website'] is for example : www.mydomain.com or http://www.mydomain.de ...

```
 elseif(strlen($_POST['website'])>0)
 {
     if(preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/", $_POST['website']))
     {
          echo"URL ok";
     }
     else
     {
          echo"URL not ok"; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about how it doesn't work. What is a sample input value that gets the wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

This one does the job:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

It validates valid urls with our without `http(s)://`

The Original

```
/^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/
```

Comment: i've changed ist but it wont work - evertime the result is "not OK"

if(!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/$", $_POST['website']))
  { echo"URL not ok";}
  else
  { echo"URL ok"; }

Comment: This validates the url input as ok. Lose the `!` in your if clause. This validates http://www.example.com, https://www.example.com, example.com, www.example.com, example.com?test.ex as correct.

Comment: it seems like i#m stupid totay, but i can enter what i want, the result is everytime "false"...?

if(preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/$", $_POST['website'])){ echo"URL ok";}else{ echo"URL not ok"; }

Comment: Post the code in your question that is handling this validation and the input that is going in there.

Comment: I've spotted a boo boo in my code. It's updated now. The `/` should be after the `$`

Comment: ok, but the following urls will be mark up as valid, i think its wrong.`http://www.mysite, http://www.my site`